# Connect to a symbian mobile from a vb.net project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, symbian

I need to connect a symbian mobile to my application to do a transfer of  information between my vb.net windows application and my mobile
i'm looking to have a software on the mobile side to send the information
can any one help me with this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [Nokia PC Suite Connectivity API](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/bd896b31-92ba-4624-aa9d-ebf732e7cc0d/Nokia_PC_Suite_Connectivity_API_1_1.html) for such tasks.